# Create "L" shape curved line with dynamic data

Tags: android, line, draw, dynamic-data

I want to draw a pure dynamic view like below image

[image]

I have two arraylist

```
List<String> type and List<Float> level;
```

**type** have *name*(max,type1,type2, etc) and **level** have *marker value* of type

**level** will always lie between 0 to 1 and **type** will be a string, value of both **level** and **type** will come from server. We have two fixed label - *min* and *max*.

Suppose I got .4 for min and .5 for max from server then all **type**(type1, type2, type3, etc) will lie between .4 and .5 . Then all rest of **types** should be arrange like crooked line, but if we get value for min is .001 and for max .9 then we have enough space to show rest of labels, in that case we don’t need to show by crooked line or marker. But I don’t have any idea how to achieve it or from where I can start. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance to all.

If above design is bit complex then please give me some reference or link to achieve below design.
[image]

It would be great favor if i am able to do this simpler one(above image).

I have tried below code in onCreate() block.

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = viewbar.getViewTreeObserver();
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ResourceAsColor" })
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            viewbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            viewWidth = viewbar.getWidth();
            viewHeight = viewbar.getHeight();

            DefineType definetype = new DefineType();   
            float maxvalue = Collections.max(definetype.frameCalLevels);
            float minvalue = Collections.min(definetype.frameCalLevels);
            min.setText(definetype.frameCalType.get(0).toString());
            max.setText(definetype.frameCalType.get(4).toString());
            float density = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int[] posXY = new int[2];
            viewbar.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
            int x = posXY[0];         
            int y = posXY[1];       

            DrawView drawView;
            drawView = new DrawView(MainActivity.this, x, y,density);
            //drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            drawView.setX((float)((x*density/160))+viewWidth+180);
            drawView.setX((float) ((float)((y*density/160))));

            drawView.invalidate();
            ll.addView(drawView);    

        }
    });

}
```

and my inner class to draw view is below

```
class   DrawView extends View {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        float mx,  my,  mdensity;
        Paint mBGPaint, mTXTPaint,mLINEPaint,mBRDPaint;
        public DrawView(Context context, float x, float y, float density) {
            super(context);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);         

            mx = x;
            my = y;         
            mdensity = density;
        }
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            init();

            mLINEPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);

            //draw rect
            canvas.drawRect(100,100,200,200,mBGPaint);
            //draw rect border
            canvas.drawRect(100,100,200,200,mBRDPaint);
            //draw text
            canvas.drawText("min", 250, 460, mTXTPaint);
            //draw line
            canvas.drawLine(50, 150, 100, 150, mLINEPaint);

        }
        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        public void init() {

            //rectangle background
            mBGPaint = new Paint();
            mBGPaint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);

            //your text
            mTXTPaint = new Paint();
            mTXTPaint.setColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);

            //your line
            mLINEPaint = new Paint();
            mLINEPaint.setColor(0xFFFF00FF);

            //rectangle border
            mBRDPaint = new Paint();
            mBRDPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mBRDPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            mBRDPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
        }
    }
```

My XML design is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/ll">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rect" >
    </View>


</LinearLayout>
```

By above code i am getting below screen, so its not appropriate. What i am missing here.? Please suggest me how to move our drawer up? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use custom View with custom onDraw:

That is,

```
public class myView extended View {
public myView(Context ctx) {
super(ctx);
init();
}
public void init(){
paint = new Paint();
}
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
//loop here
      canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);//your some positions.
canvas.drawRect(....)
canvas.drawText(...)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
For your second example:

```
init() {

//rectangle background
mBGPaint = new Paint();
mBGPaint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);

//your text
mTXTPaint = new Paint();
mTXTPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

//your line
mLINEPaint = new Paint();
mLINEPaint.setColor(0xFFFF00FF);

//rectangle border
mBRDPaint = new Paint();
mBRDPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
mBRDPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
mBRDPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
}

onDraw(...) {

//draw rect
canvas.drawRect(100,100,200,200,mBGPaint);
//draw rect border
canvas.drawRect(100,100,200,200,mBRDPaint);
//draw text
canvas.drawRect(100,100,mTXTPaint);
//draw line
canvas.drawLine(50, 150, 100, 150, mLINEPaint);
}
```

Comment: I am really glad, will you please suggest me based on updated question. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Obviously, Your answer helped me a lot. But if could able to explain how can i put new canvas in new position dynamically; means setting setX() and setY(). I tried it but not working for me.

Comment: use View.invalidate() to redraw the view. That is, setup position by setX() and setY(), than use this.invalidate() or (outside this class) v.invalidate()

Comment: I update my question. Please i need your small help.

Comment: @Dilshad , what do you want to achieve?

Comment: How to put my custom draw over long rectangle bar? But It is coming below rectangle bar, If you have any idea in code context. please suggest me.

Comment: @Dilshad , do you mean 'the roundedrectangle bar' is in another view? If 'yes' use not linearlayout but relativealayout to draw view one over the other.

Comment: Thanks .. for your response.  I am adding view dynamically. In XML i have drawn only long rectangle bar, and drawer trying to add in LinerLayout dynamically with setX() and setY() position , but its not working. If you need any more clarification Please feel free to ping me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101567/discussion-between-vyacheslav-and-dilshad).

Answer (score 0):

This is really a big question. And I think no one can give you a definitive answers for that.

My advise is baby steps:

1-Put a button on the screen and try to create 3 lines to get a crooked line effect. Calculate the length of all 3 parts of the crooked line by using a start point(at the beginning you can start from the middle of the screen) and end point(buttons final destination)

2- If you know start and end position for the button you can calculate the line2 length easily. For the line1 and line3 you also need to pass another parameter for your calculate function(by the way you should have it) where to start to crook.

After you complete this task then there are more.
3- You should then place 5 buttons on the screen and assemble their cooked lines by using the function you defined before.
4- According to your start and end point your cooked line should go up and down.
5- Now you are capable of creating cooked lines. It is time to calculate for the real task.

6- You should calculate the required space available and somehow figure out if the buttons will fit in. If not you should put the button in second lane and then use your magical L draw method to connect them to a calculated start position(you should have calculated the y position of the start points for every buttons.)

It is go on. Just try to split your assignment into little pieces and then try to complete each of them easily without any headache.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see updated question. If you have any lead please help me.